# Merge Rows in SQL Table based on two table values

Tags: sql, database, concatenation, ssms

I have a table with travel details. Details are getting saved in distributed manner. I need to merge the rows based on Source and Destination. My Source is A and Final Destination is D, I need to merge all the 3 rows into 1 with sum of time and distance, based on date of travel.

[Table Details and Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoNqj.png)

I tried using Concatenate but not able to do based on conditions. Not sure how to combine rows of one table based on values of another.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) If you want to provide data do so in a *consumable* format. Ideally sample data should be DDL and DML statements, but minimally data should be provided in a markdown table. Images are *not* helpful as we cannot use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` statement and then aggregate:

```
SELECT Table2.Date,
       Table2.CarID,
       Table2.Source,
       Table2.Destination,
       SUM(Table1.Distance) AS Distance,
       SUM(Table1.[Time(Hours)]) AS [Time(Hours)]
FROM Table2
LEFT JOIN Table1
     ON  (Table1.Source BETWEEN Table2.Source AND Table2.Destination
     OR  Table1.Destination BETWEEN Table2.Source AND Table2.Destination)
     AND Table2.Date = Table1.Date
     AND Table2.CarID = Table1.CarID
GROUP BY Table2.Date,
         Table2.CarID,
         Table2.Source,
         Table2.Destination
```

This assumes that your `Source` and `Destination` never overlap - like in the example you provided.

Comment: This solution is not working if the source and destination are not alphabetical.